# How can I configure Wolverine for use with OrchardCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcore, wolverine

I am trying to configure Wolverine in a .NET 7 application that is leveraging the OrchardCore framework.
The problem arises from Wolverine swapping out the IoC container, but specifically that it needs to do this with the WebApplicationBuilder.Host property.
As soon as it calls `routes.MapWolverineEndpoints()`, it fails to cast the service provider to a `Lamar.IContainer` as shown in the exception below.

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider' to type 'Lamar.IContainer'.'
```

Here is the entire `Program.cs` from an MRE I built to demonstrate the issue:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Oakton;
using Wolverine;
using Wolverine.Http;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddOrchardCore()
    .AddMvc()
     // Orchard Specific Pipeline
     .ConfigureServices( services => {
         services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
         services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
         {
             c.EnableAnnotations();
             c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
             {
                 Version = "1.0.0",
                 Title = "OrchardCore.Mvc.WebApiWothWolverine"
             });
         });
     })
     .Configure( (app, routes, services) => {
         routes.MapWolverineEndpoints();
         var env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
         env ??= app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostEnvironment>() as IWebHostEnvironment;

         if (env?.IsDevelopment() ?? false)
         {
             app.UseSwagger();
             app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
             {
                 c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "An ASP.NET Core Web API");
             });
         }
     });

builder.Host.UseWolverine();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseOrchardCore();

await app.RunOaktonCommands(args);
```

The MRE repo can be found [here](https://github.com/daerogami/OrchardCore.Mvc.WebApiWithWolverine).

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like below, and the issue could be fixed.

[image]

```
using Lamar.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Oakton;
using Wolverine;
using Wolverine.Http;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddOrchardCore();
// Orchard Specific Pipeline
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.EnableAnnotations();
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "1.0.0",
        Title = "OrchardCore.Mvc.WebApiWothWolverine"
    });
});


builder.Host.UseWolverine();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "An ASP.NET Core Web API");
    });
    app.MapWolverineEndpoints();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseOrchardCore();

await app.RunOaktonCommands(args);
```

Comment: By pulling Wolverine out of the OrchardCore configuration, Wolverine endpoints do not have access to the OrchardCore or Swagger infrastructure. You'll notice in SwaggerUI only the ValuesController is showing up and not the GetAccount endpoint.

Comment: @MarkClark [Is this effect what you want?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8MEF.png)

Comment: Negative, both controllers and endpoints should be visible from the same SwaggerUI instance. I should probably also have the controllers and endpoints injecting an OrchardCore service to better indicate the intended dependencies.

Comment: I appreciate your continued effort and I feel guilty pointing out that the lastest change does not fix the issue. Controllers and endpoints are now being registered outside of the OrchardCore tenant shell; so tenant-specific services are not available such as IShellConfiguration or IShellFeaturesManager. I have updated the repo to inject these dependencies for verification.